# Class Forward Declaration C++

Tags: c++, class, forward-declaration

I was following a tutorial on the Observer Pattern and I came across the following problem.

Namely, I have the following base classes:

```
class Subject;
class Observer;
```

Next, I want to define two more classes

```
class StockGrabber: public Subject {
    //...
    //the constructor involves a StockObserver object
    StockGrabber(StockObserver so){....};

}
class StockObserver: public Observer {
    //...
    StockObserver(StockGrabber sg) {....};
}
```

Is there any way I could use forward declaration so that StockGrabber would know that StockObserver exists? Given their interdependence, I couldn't just swap the positions of the two classes.

How should I go about solving this issue? (the original tutorial was written in Java, but I'm trying to implement it in C++) Thank you!

Comment: The equivalent code in Java would imply reference semantics, whereas your C++ code shows value semantics. You probably want to change to use reference semantics.  To answer your question, one of the function bodies will need to be defined out-of-line in order to use the forward declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declaration is not enough, you have to make some change on the StockObserver::StockGrabber(StockObserver so) member functions' signature, because if you pass the argument by value you need the definition not only the declaration of the parameters' class. If you pass by reference, then the declaration is enough for declaring the function, but that declaration is not surely enough for implement that function, so may be you will have to define the function outside of the class after StockObserver class defintion. Look at the code below, an it will be more understandable.

```
class Subject{ /* ... */ };
class Observer{ /* ... */ };

class StockObserver;

class StockGrabber: public Subject {
    //...
    //the constructor involves a StockObserver object
    StockGrabber(StockObserver& so); // class StockObserver is declared before StockGrabber::StockGrabber(StockObserver&).
};

class StockObserver: public Observer {
    //...
    StockObserver(StockGrabber sg) { /* ... */ };
};

StockGrabber::StockGrabber(StockObserver& so){ /* ... */ } // class StockObserver is defined before StockGrabber::StockGrabber(StockObserver&).
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use forward declaration of `StockObserver`. The following program builds successfully.

```
class Subject {};
class Observer {};

class StockObserver;

class StockGrabber: public Subject {
    StockGrabber(StockObserver so);

};

class StockObserver: public Observer {
    StockObserver(StockGrabber sg);
};

StockGrabber::StockGrabber(StockObserver so) {}

StockObserver::StockObserver(StockGrabber sg) {}

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

It's not clear how you wish to make use of the arguments to the constructors. There will be challenges when you use the arguments to the constructors.

Comment: @R_Sahu: thanks, but when I compiled it gave the error 'Variable has incomplete type 'StockGrabber'. Any hints?'

Comment: Although this compiles, it's not possible to actually create any instances of the classes involved.

Comment: @R_Sahu, this only works because the constructor is just the default one. Let's say if one fills in the details, then the error will occur. The way is to make a forward declaration, and then declare the function inside the class, and the define the function after the StockObserver class.

Comment: @Newbie, it will be good if you can post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the problem.

Comment: @R_Sahu Thank you for your input. Your code compiled but mine didn't because I had more details in the definition of the functions, there were variables which were not yet defined until later in the code.